# Variable in a link

Tags: thymeleaf

My code:

```html
<script th:text="${theme}">test</script>
<link th:href="@{/themes/${theme}/general/general.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Result:

```html
<script>holmes</script>
<link href="/themes/${theme}/general/general.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Well, the variable "theme" contains a value. But when it comes to that link creation, we can see ${theme} instead of holmes.

Comment: Remove the @{} around the link. It doesn't evaluate recursively

Comment: I have made like this:  <link th:href="/themes/${theme}/general/general.css" rel="stylesheet" /> And it blew up: Could not parse as expression: "/themes/${theme}/general/general.css"

Shall I calculate the whole path somewhere, store it in a variable and use it here? Something like:  th:with="path = '/themes/${theme}/general/general.css'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string concatenation like this:

```
<link th:href="@{'/themes/'+${theme}+'/general/general.css'}" rel="stylesheet" />
```